# Rename files with folders' names and move them to one big folder

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a folder with 40 subfolders each containing 20~21 jpg all named *01.jpg* -> *20.jpg* The subfolders are named *Nature_Set_01* to *Nature_Set_40*

I'd like to have all the pictures moved in one folder with names like *Nature_Set_01_01.jpg* to *Nature_Set_40_20.jpg* or something like that, I don't really care about the names.

Here is a tree if I'm not clear:

```
├── Nature_Set_01
│   ├── 01.jpg
│   ├── 02.jpg
│   ├── ...
│   └── 20.jpg
├── Nature_Set_02
│   ├── 01.jpg
│   ├── 02.jpg
│   ├── ...
│   ├── 21.jpg
├── ...
├── Nature_Set_40
│   ├── 01.jpg
│   ├── 02.jpg
│   ├── ...
│   ├── 20.jpg
```

I'm not a bash guru, I tried to understand how to do it but I failed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute this script in the parent directory.

```
mkdir folder
for file in Nature_Set_*/*.jpg; do
    mv "$file" "folder/${file/\//_}"
done
```

- It creates the directory `folder`
- and then loops through files matching `Nature_Set_*/*.jpg`, moving each file found to `"folder/${file/\//_}"`.
- This last construct, `${file/\//_}`, is a special form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), whose skeleton is `${parameter/pattern/replacement}`. Since `/` is already the delimiter of the construct, it needs to be escaped if it is to appear in `pattern`. Thus `/` is replaced by `_` in the file name.
  Example: `Nature_Set_01/01.jpg` becomes `Nature_Set_01_01.jpg`.

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect. I think I understand your script, but that thing `${file/\//_}` it scares me.

Comment: @Colar Glad to help. I have edited it to explain `${file/\//_}` better. If this solves your problem, please accept the answer.