# Rename files from different directories with their paths

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rename, batch-rename

I don't know if I'm making sense but, this is roughly what I'm dealing with, and just in case I'll include that some folders have .jpg in the name:

```
Photos$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   └── X
│   │       └── Y
│   │           ├── A
│   │           │   └── image.jpg
│   │           └── B
│   │               └── image.jpg
│   └──2.jpg
│      └── X
│          └── Y
│              ├── A
│              │   └── image.jpg
│              └── B
│                  └── image.jpg
│
└── 2
    ├── 1.jpg
    │   └── X
    │       └── Y
    │           ├── A
    │           │   └── image.jpg
    │           └── B
    │               └── image.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    │   └── X
    │       └── Y
    │           ├── A
    │           │   └── image.jpg
    │           ├── B
    │           │   └── image.jpg
```

Ideally, through the directories names, I would like it to recognize the correct order and rename the images accordingly `1.jpg` ... `8.jpg`.

If that's too complicated then rename them with their path:

- `1_1.jpg_X_Y_A_image.jpg`
- `2_2.jpg_X_Y_B_image.jpg`
- etc.

... and maybe a way to extract all the actual jpg at once.

I tried (this answer]([Rename files with folders' names and move them to one big folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286673/rename-files-with-folders-names-and-move-them-to-one-big-folder)), and I'm guessing I should adapt it better to how many subfolders I have, but I don't know how.

Here's a way I tried to fit in my directory:

```
user:~/home/test$ mkdir folder
user:~/home/test$ for file in Photos*/*/*.jpg/X*/Y*/*/*.jpg; do
> mv "$file" "folder/${file/\//_}"
> done
```

the result is always

```
mv: cannot move 'Photos/1/1.jpg/X/Y/A/image.jpg' to 'folder/Photos/1/1.jpg/X/Y/A/image.jpg': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'Photos/2/2.jpg/X/Y/B/image.jpg' to 'folder/Photos/2/2.jpg/X/Y/B/image.jpg': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? There are more than a 1000 images, so I can't do this manually!

Comment: Please make sure that your code matches your `tree`, so we can get a better idea of your problem. I don't see any "Natur_Set_*" directory. Also please post the full error message.

Comment: edited it, sorry it was a mess, I had forgotten to include an additional layer of subfolders

Comment: You are lucky that it didn't work, or you would have overwritten the files, because you don't rename them. Q: Is the order for the ne naming important? What is the rule for it? Sorted lexically  or what ?

Comment: yes the correct order is fundamental, it needs to be alphabetical, but the path is ok too, I can sort it out

Comment: I understand, you may be omitted a `/` in `${file/\//_}` ==> `${file//\//_}`

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly, you saved me hours of work

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. @ArnaudValmary consider turning your comments to an answer so that OP can accept it.